# I want to calculate session_id for my list of events with T-SQL query

Tags: t-sql, row-number, rownum

The following is a list of events. 
I want to calculate the `session_id` column in my list of events. 
After that I try to calculate time between events in each session.
Each `session_id` should be started from `event_name = "app_open"`, ordered by `timestamp`. In the bellow table you can see data that I have (3 first columns) and the last one that I want to calculate.

How can I do it with T-SQL?

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>event_name</th><th>event_number</th><th>timestamp</th><th>session_id</th></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:04</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:38</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 02:55:13</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>appsflyer_init</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:54</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 02:57:25</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>7</td><td>2015-09-10 03:01:27</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>8</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:01</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>9</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:44</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:04:21</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:06:07</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:08:40</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:09:49</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:07</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:28</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:11:35</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:13:40</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:17:46</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:25:02</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You will have to explain better what you're trying to do, and maybe tell us what you've tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

As Jony said, you will have to explain better what you're trying to do. The posted data is the input data or the expected result? If it's the input data, you already have a `session_id` there; do you simply need to calculate the interval between events? If yes, try something like this (in SQL Server 2012 or later):

```
DECLARE @X XML='<table><tbody><tr><th>event_name</th><th>event_number</th><th>timestamp</th><th>session_id</th></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:04</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:38</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 02:55:13</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>appsflyer_init</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:54</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 02:57:25</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>7</td><td>2015-09-10 03:01:27</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>8</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:01</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>9</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:44</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:04:21</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:06:07</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:08:40</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:09:49</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:07</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:28</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:11:35</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:13:40</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:17:46</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:25:02</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>'
--SELECT @x
SELECT *, CONVERT(time,timestamp-LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY event_number)) as interval
FROM (
    SELECT  c.value('td[1]','varchar(100)') as event_name,
            c.value('td[2]','int') as event_number,
            c.value('td[3]','datetime') as timestamp,
            c.value('td[4]','int') as session_id
    FROM @x.nodes('/table/tbody/tr[td!=""]') t(c)
) q
```

If the posted data is the expected result, then please post the input data.

**Later edit**:
If you want to compute the `session_id` based on the `event_number`, you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @X XML='<table><tbody><tr><th>event_name</th><th>event_number</th><th>timestamp</th><th>session_id</th></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:04</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 02:54:38</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 02:55:13</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>appsflyer_init</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 02:56:54</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 02:57:25</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>7</td><td>2015-09-10 03:01:27</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>8</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:01</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>9</td><td>2015-09-10 03:02:44</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:04:21</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>crashlytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:06:07</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>parse_init</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:07:27</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:08:40</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:09:49</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>app_open</td><td>1</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:07</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>googleanalytics_init</td><td>2</td><td>2015-09-10 03:10:28</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_popup</td><td>3</td><td>2015-09-10 03:11:35</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_get</td><td>4</td><td>2015-09-10 03:13:40</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>login_success</td><td>5</td><td>2015-09-10 03:17:46</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>lobby_displayed</td><td>6</td><td>2015-09-10 03:25:02</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>'
--SELECT @x
SELECT *, CONVERT(time,timestamp-LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY event_number)) as interval
FROM (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY row_num-event_number) AS session_id
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS row_num
        FROM (
            SELECT  c.value('td[1]','varchar(100)') as event_name,
                    c.value('td[2]','int') as event_number,
                    c.value('td[3]','datetime') as timestamp
            FROM @x.nodes('/table/tbody/tr[td!=""]') t(c)
        ) q1
    ) q2
) q3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no session_id, I added the column in Excel to show what I want to receive.

Comment: Do you have the event_number? Please edit your question to post the input data and describe how do you want to compute the session_id.

Comment: edited the question, but I don't know how to compute the session_id. This is my question. I tried to do it with ROWNUM() but is not working...

Comment: I have edited the answer to compute the `session_id` (using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`).

Comment: Thank you, Razvan Socol, I am on vacation till 28.09, only after I will try your code ;)